# how to setstate in handleclick in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im a beginner concerning react .i do not know why setState in the handleclick function doesn't work properly . this is the code

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { isDark: false }
    }
    handleOnClick = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({ isDark: !prevState.isDark }))
        if (this.state.isDark === 'true') {
            setTheme('theme-dark')
        }
        else setTheme('theme-light')
    }
render() {

        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleOnClick}>
          </button>
```

so when i click the button the state of isDark will always be false , that means setState is not working i guess

Comment: I don't think so we can setState in a way you are doing try setting state like this `this.setState({isDark:true})`

Comment: a) `this.setState` is asynchronous so `if (this.state.isDark` won't work. `setState` does have [a callback that you can use when the state is updated](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). But b) I'm completely perplexed how you're combining `this.setState` (class component) with a functional component hook(?) `setTheme`.

Comment: if (this.state.isDark === 'true') {
            setTheme('theme-dark')
        } is the problem i reckon

Comment: the problem was pretty simple  the condition statement was if ( ...  === 'true' ) instead of (... === true )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that the react lifecycle will update the state after the sync function handleOnClick complete. You may try this way:

```js
handleOnClick = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const isDark = !prevState.isDark;
    if (isDark === true) {
      setTheme('theme-dark');
    } else setTheme('theme-light');
    return {...prevState, isDark};
  })
};
```

or using lifecycle method
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

```js
componentDidUpdate(){
 if (this.state.isDark === true) {
   setTheme('theme-dark');
 } else setTheme('theme-light');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write this

```js
this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
```

at the end of your `constructor` and in `handleOnClick` function create local variable to save new value:

```js
handleOnClick = () => {
    const isDark = !this.state.isDark;

    this.setState({ isDark: isDark });

    if (isDark === true) {
        setTheme('theme-dark')
    } else {
        setTheme('theme-light');
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this but the issue is the setTheme is considering the state false when i click the button

Comment: @Toto because it will use new value after next rendering

Comment: That's not the problem as @Toto is already using the arrow function.

Comment: @Toto save in some local variable `const isDark` in `handleOnClick` function the `!this.state.isDark` value and then check in `if` `isDark`'s value and in the `this.setState` also use this variable

Answer (score 0):

the code is correct but in the conditional statement there is a huge mistake i was comparing `this.state.isDark ==='true'`

Comment: Are you sure that this `if (this.state.isDark === 'true')` statement uses actual value of `this.state.isDark`? Or you really need old value?

Comment: this.state.isDark === 'true' must be this.state.isDark === true instead  ! but the code is correct , since the handleOnClick function will change the state whenever the button is clicked

Comment: But you in `if` statement get the old value instead of changed value

Comment: ah yes that's right ! i am sorry i didn't pay attention to this

Comment: Can you please approve my answer and upvote please if it fix your problems and was useful?) I will be very grateful!